# Symfony problem with range Datetime (form)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I don't understand my problem.
If you can just give me an idea.
I have a dateTime field who works but
my field years have a bizzare range (2015-2025).
I want to have a bigger range (e.g : 1960-2040).

```
class BookType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('author')
            ->add('publicationDate')
            ->add('format')
            ->add('language')
            ->add('user')
            ->add('excelFile', FileType::class,[
                'label' => 'Fichier excel (xls/xlsx file)',
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '1024k',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid xls/xlsx document',
                    ])
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here [DateType::Class Refrence](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#years). The field will have options to configure how your choice box will behave. you can simply use php's range() function to map out your Years in your code like : range(1960, 2040)

```
$builder->add('field', DateType::Class , [
    'years' => range(date('Y')-50, date('Y')+50) // Lists 50 Years Before and After
]);
```

In your code simply use :

```
class BookType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('author')
            ->add('publicationDate', DateType::Class , [
                'years' => range(1960, date('Y')+20) // Change As eper your requirements
            ])
            ->add('format')
            ->add('language')
            ->add('user')
            ->add('excelFile', FileType::class,[
                'label' => 'Fichier excel (xls/xlsx file)',
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '1024k',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid xls/xlsx document',
                    ])
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }
```